# Some items not formatted right but the rest are

Tags: python

I do not know why some items are not formatted right, the short names seem to be fine but the longer ones throw themselfs off
https://pastebin.com/pkGL0Nwy

```
prices = {}
groceries = []

file = open("grocery_store_price_list.txt", "r")
for strx in file:
    strs = list(filter(None, strx.strip().split(" ")))
    prices[strs[0]] = [strs[1]], [strs[2]]
file.close()

file = open("my_personal_gro_list.txt", "r")
for strx in file :
    strs = list(filter(None, strx.strip().split(" ")))
    groceries.append([strs[1], strs[0]])

headings = "{:6s} {:9s} {:6s} {:7s} {:6s}".format("item", "qty", "unit", "cost", "total")

print(headings)

finalCost = 0


for strs in groceries:
    item = strs[0]
    qty = int(strs[1])
    unit = prices[strs[0]][1]
    cost = float(prices[strs[0]][0][0])
    total = qty*cost

    finalCost += total

    print(item, qty, unit, cost, total,)
```

Comment: [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("{item}\t{qty}\t{unit}\t{cost}\t{total}".format(item=item, qty=qty, unit=unit, cost=cost, total=total))
```

Comment: Was fixing that as you commented ;)

Comment: alexisdevarennes i tried that i got ValueError: Unknown format code 's' for object of type 'int'

Comment: If this was helpful, please mark the answer as correct :) Also, if you still have issues, please update your question.